# The system cannot find the path specified. 'Could not build pakmanager package. Please make sure pakmanager is globally installed'

Tags: node.js

I got the following error when Ive used "npm install":

"

npm WARN package.json fs@0.0.1 fs is also the name of a node core module.

> coordinator@0.4.7 install C:\Users\aner\WebstormProjects\redesign\node_modules\coordinator
>   cd examples ; pakmanager build || echo 'Could not build pakmanager package. Please make sure pakmanager is globally installed'

The system cannot find the path specified.
'Could not build pakmanager package. Please make sure pakmanager is globally installed'

"

what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem installing pakmanger, here's the instruction:

https://github.com/coolaj86/node-pakmanager

Basically in the installation script 'pakmanager' is used and it must be installed in your system to execute the script successfully.